# Android AUTOINCREMENT column besides PRIMARY KEY column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table with a varchar column as Primary Key. Furthermore I want to have an autoincremented id for each row. The column for the id is called "id" not "_id". When I try to create the database, I get the error that I have an syntax error near "AUTONINCREMENT".

```
 public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
         "CREATE TABLE " + ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
         ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_USERNAME + " VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY," +
         ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT," +
         ContactEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_DISPLAY_NAME + 
         " VARCHAR(25))";
```

Comment: I've edited your post to use sqllite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the following : 
1. using string as primary key its not a good idea in general, since strings are not natural for cluster indices. 
2. AUTOINCEMRENT is possible only for INTEGER PRIMARY key which is omitted in your case

Comment: Copy that, thanks! So change the primary key to the id and make the username column unique? Furthermore is there a way to set unique not case sensitive?

Comment: @Simon, yep - in any relational db (not only sqlite) is best to have primary key of "integer type" like which means they are easy to cluster (due to the natural order on integers). In your case, making the user name as unique is a good choice since sqlite will create for you *non-clustered* index. Regarding the case sensitivity simply specify _collate nocase_ in the column definition of the relevant create table